# Not able to load ApplicationContext in Play-Spring-Hibernate application, getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, playframework

I am working on a play application with hibernate and Spring, getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal while loading the Spring-data-contxt.xml at beginning. Tried with different versions of xml-apis:xml-apis:jar, but error is not fixed.

### stack trace as follows

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [spring-context-data.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at Global.onStart(Global.java:19)
    at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.onStart(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:18)
    at play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:203)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:88)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
    at play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:87)
    at play.core.StaticApplication.<init>(ApplicationProvider.scala:52)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.createServer(NettyServer.scala:243)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:279)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$main$3.apply(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$.main(NettyServer.scala:274)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.main(NettyServer.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.startDocumentParsing(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.dom.ElementTraversal
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 55 more
```

### My build.sbt looks like,

```
name := """Shopscribed"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.1.RELEASE" % "test",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.1.9.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-search-orm" % "4.2.0.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.6",
  "commons-dbcp" % "commons-dbcp" % "1.2",
  "cglib" % "cglib" % "2.2.2",
  "xml-apis" % "xml-apis" % "1.4.01"
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

### My Spring-context-data.xml looks like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="...>

    <description>ShopScribed.com</description>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers, configs, models, services"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/shopscribed"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="possible"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="-1" />
    </bean>

    <!--bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>entity.Artist</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.shopscribed.domain" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">var/lucene/indexes</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.search.lucene_version">LUCENE_36</prop>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
                <prop key="show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id = "transactionManager" class = "org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name = "sessionFactory" ref = "sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="indexData" class="com.shopscribed.index.util.IndexExistingData"
        init-method="init"></bean-->
</beans>
```

### and Global.java

```
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    import play.Application;
    //import configs.AppConfig;
    //import configs.DataConfig;
    //import play.Logger;
    import play.GlobalSettings;

    public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

        private ApplicationContext context;

        @Override
        public void onStart(Application app) {
            // context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class,
            // DataConfig.class);
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context-data.xml");
        }

        @Override
        public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> clazz) {
            return context.getBean(clazz);
        }

    }
```

I have manually downloaded xml-apis.jar and added as External Jars from eclipse buildpath options, still problem is not solved ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution here,

http://swordsystems.com/2011/06/29/xerces-and-xml-api-dependency-hell/

had to change the xml-api version in build.sbt. My new build.sbt looks like,

```
name := """Shopscribed"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaCore,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-context" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.1.RELEASE",
  "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.1.RELEASE" % "test",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.1.9.Final",
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-search-orm" % "4.2.0.Final",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.6",
  "commons-dbcp" % "commons-dbcp" % "1.4",
  "cglib" % "cglib" % "2.2.2",
  "xml-apis" % "xml-apis" % "1.3.04"
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

Comment: You should accept this answer since it fixed your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you miss the `xml-apis.jar` in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath.

Comment: I have manually downloaded xml-apis.jar and added as External Jars from eclipse buildpath options, still problem is not solved ...

Comment: How do you run your program? If you run it in a webcontainer you have add the jar to the classpath of these container. The eclipse buildpath ia irrelevant.

Comment: But Jens, I am running from Activator's Browser(Netty Server)

Comment: Jens, Not sure how to add classpath for Netty while running for Activator browser.. could you please give me a hint?

Comment: got the solution here,

http://swordsystems.com/2011/06/29/xerces-and-xml-api-dependency-hell/